# Conditional expectation given an independent and dependent variable

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Given $X,Y,Z$ with $X$ and $Z$ independent, is $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y,Z] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]$?

This has come up a few times when working on a separate problem - I don't think it is true (memories from a course) but haven't been able to put together a counterexample. Intuitively, it seems that conditioning on $Z$ should influence my understanding of how $Y$ and $X$ interact, which would make the equality false.  Since I didn't find a similar question on the site I thought it would be useful for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Suppose that $X$ and $Z$ are independent with
$$X \sim U([-1,1])\\
Z \sim U([-1,1])\\
Y = X + Z$$

Then: $\ \ \ \operatorname{E}[X\ |\ Y=0] = 0$

But: $\ \ \ \  \ \operatorname{E}[X\ |\ Y=0,\ Z=1] = -1$

This phenomenon, where two independent variables become dependent in the presence of a third, is known as [conditional dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_dependence)